# using existing code of iphone objective-c code in monotouch (Range Slider in monotouch iphone)

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, uislider

I'm trying to create a range slider for my monotouch iphone application.

I have a search and found this source:
[CMRangeSlider](https://github.com/cmezak/CMRangeSlider)

the code has a class that implement rangeslider. the problems is that the source is objective c and if i want to rewrite it by c# it takes so much time from me.
Is there any fast and easy way that we reuse the existing objective-c codes in C# monotouch?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Monotouch project from the RangeSlider: https://github.com/nicwise/RangeSliderMonoTouch

It's based on another project: http://buildmobile.com/wicked-ios-range-slider-part-one/
but should do the same I guess